# Delete object from array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just want to delete the `specTplItemDropped()` function parameter `item` from this data structure:

```
this.areas:
      items:
          item:
```

code:

```
public specTplItemDropped(index, item, external, type, area1) {
    let newArray = this.areas.map(areaV => {
        let a = areaV.items.filter(itemV => {
            let b = itemV.id !== item.id;
            return b;
        });
        return a;
    });

    console.log(newArray);
```

The new array should be the same as the old array, minus one item. But it is very different:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share input data and output data? (No images)

Comment: It looks like your input data is not an array of arrays, but an array of objects (here _Resources_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is an array of objects, but you're returning an array rather than an object from the `.map()` call. You need to return a copy of the original object, with the new array of items.

```
function specTplItemDropped(index, item, external, type, area1) {
    let newArray = this.areas.map(areaV => {
        let a = areaV.items.filter(itemV => {
            let b = itemV.id !== item.id;
            return b;
        });
        return Object.assign({items: a, itemCount: a.length}, areaV);
    });

    console.log(newArray);
}
```

Comment: Then his _itemCount_ variable would have a wrong value. Maybe it is important for OP